# C# SharePoint CAML Query Ignoring Where Clause

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I am executing this query which returns results...however it is returning ALL results, not the one specified in my where clause.  How should I re-write this so that ONLY the ID in the where clause is returned?

```
string server = "blahblahblah";
string msn = "14318";
var ctx = new ClientContext(server);
ver web = ctx.Web;
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Attendance");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name='recID'/>
<FieldRef Name='MasterID'/>
<FieldRef Name='totalsalevalue'/>
</ViewFields><where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeID' /><Value Type='Text'>"+msn+"</Value></Eq><Where>";
var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

ctx.Load(listItemCollection, eachItem => eachItem.Include(
                                          item => item,
                                          item => item["recID"],
                                          item => item["totalsalevalue"],
                                          item => item["MasterID"]));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem li in listItemCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(li["recID"]);
    Console.WriteLine(li["MasterID"]);
    Console.WriteLine(li["totalsalevalue"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to SharePoint to test this right now, but try this:

```
<View>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='recID'/>
    <FieldRef Name='MasterID'/>
    <FieldRef Name='totalsalevalue'/>
  </ViewFields>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='EmployeeID' />
        <Value Type='Text'>"+msn+"</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

And as a test, try just the Where portion to see if it works:

```
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='EmployeeID' />
        <Value Type='Text'>"+msn+"</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
```

Comment: Adding in the <View> and <Query> tags solved.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You're not passing your camlQuery object to the GetItems method. You should change this line:

```
var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
```

to this:

```
var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
```

Comment: Even after changing to your recommend ALL data is returned

Comment: You should check two more things: 1) Is the EmployeeID column really the text column? 2) How do you create the ViewXml string (camlQuery.ViewXml = ...) because the way it is written in the original question doesn't compile (you should escape double quotes in the string or use single quotes).

Comment: See edit -> and yes EmployeeID is really the text column

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not valid:

```
<where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeID' /><Value Type='Text'>"+msn+"</Value></Eq><Where>
```

Probably should be:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeID' /><Value Type='Text'>"+msn+"</Value></Eq></Where>
```

Comment: Even after making the change from where to Where all data is still returned